# perl получить нужное значение из XML

Tags: perl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ЖурналТК="ТК">
    <Trek>
        <Zakazchik>Иван</Zakazchik>
                <TrekCod>17</TrekCod>
    </Trek>
    <Trek>
        <Zakazchik>Сергей</Zakazchik>
                <TrekCod>2</TrekCod>
    </Trek>
    <Trek>
        <Zakazchik>Алексей</Zakazchik>
                <TrekCod>3</TrekCod>
    </Trek>


</Trek>
```

есть Xml !перебрав в цикле все теги `Trek` и проверяя у каждого `TrekCod`, пробую вывести `Zakazchik`,с `TrekCod` 3

```
my $xml = XML::Simple->new();
my $list = $xml->XMLin('trek.xml');

for my $Trek ( keys $list->{Trek} ) {
 if ($list->{Trek}->{$Trek}->{TrekCod} == 3) {
        print "$Trek\n";
    }
}
```

Не работает. В чем может быть ошибка?

**Обновление**

Исправил XML, но все равно не работает.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TK>
    <Trek>
        <Zakazchik>Иван</Zakazchik>
                <TrekCod>17</TrekCod>
    </Trek>
    <Trek>
        <Zakazchik>Сергей</Zakazchik>
                <TrekCod>2</TrekCod>
    </Trek>
    <Trek>
        <Zakazchik>Алексей Экспорт</Zakazchik>
                <TrekCod>3</TrekCod>
    </Trek>


</TK>
```

Comment: у Вас xml немного не валидный. Возможно в этом и причина.

Comment: что именно с ним  не то.

Comment: первое - странный открывающий тег - `<ЖурналТК="ТК">` и парный к нему `</Trek>` - имена этих тегов должны совпадать. А внутри них много вложенных `Trek`, что хоть и корректно, но наводит на раздумия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вначале нужно добавить модули strict и warnings (или явно указать хотя бы `use 5.012`). Тогда перл сам бы подсказал, что не так.

Исправленный код выглядит так

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here

use XML::Simple;

use strict;
use warnings;

# да, я ручками указал содержимое, так как лень ещё и файл создавать 
my $xml_str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <TK> <Trek> <Zakazchik>Иван</Zakazchik> <TrekCod>17</TrekCod> </Trek> <Trek> <Zakazchik>Сергей</Zakazchik> <TrekCod>2</TrekCod> </Trek> <Trek> <Zakazchik>Алексей Экспорт</Zakazchik> <TrekCod>3</TrekCod> </Trek> </TK>';

my $xml = XML::Simple->new();
my $list = $xml->XMLin( $xml_str);

# а тут нужно явно указать, что это массив
for my $Trek ( @{$list->{Trek}} ) {

 if ($Trek->{TrekCod} == 3) {
        print "$Trek->{Zakazchik}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Все работает супер.Только результат выводит  РђР»РµРєСЃРµР№ Р­РєСЃРїРѕСЂС‚

Comment: Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: видимо из за того, что вы используете консоль без поддержки utf-8, а файл в ней. На винде запускаем?

Comment: да на винде запускаю

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370720/perl-printing-unicode-strings-to-the-windows-console

Comment: ок. буду разбираться.если будут вопросы буду обращаться.